# Using two queries or using relation to insert data on two tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, one is "users" and another is "wallet". The wallet table is related to user table as "hasOne". So i have a scenario which needs to update both user table and also wallet table.

But the problem is , i have only related wallet to user with hasOne. And i dont know what i am doing i good approach or bad one. Actually am querying two times separately for user and wallet.

So from the code, first am querying user to increment a count and again querying wallet to execute other queries. Is this effective ? or can i related as "belongsTo" from wallet to user in order to do everything in a single query ?

Please guide me a best approach.

```
$level_count = User::findOrFail($h)->increment('level_count', 1);
$wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', $h)->first();
$wallet->increment('wallet_balance',200);
$wallet->wallet_logs()->create(['wallet_logs' => 'Commission INR 200 
Credited']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is now, your code executes these statements (as shown by the very useful [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)):

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1
update `users` set `level_count` = `level_count` + 1, `users`.`updated_at` = '2019-07-25 14:05:44' where `id` = 1
select * from `wallets` where `user_id` = 1 limit 1
update `wallets` set `wallet_balance` = `wallet_balance` + 200, `wallets`.`updated_at` = '2019-07-25 14:05:44' where `id` = 1
insert into `wallet_logs` (`wallet_logs`, `wallet_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('Commission INR 200 \r\n     Credited', 1, '2019-07-25 14:05:44', '2019-07-25 14:05:44')
```

Which works, but the code is not very neat as no relation between User and Wallet is used. I would rewrite it to:

```
$user = User::with('wallet')->find($h);
$user->increment('level_count', 1);
$user->wallet->increment('wallet_balance', 200);
$user->wallet->wallet_logs()->create(['wallet_logs' => 'Commission INR 200 Credited']);
```

It will need this relation in `User.php`:

```
public function wallet()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Wallet');
}
```

This does not execute any less queries though. Unless you are willing to construct a (relatively complex) UPDATE query with a JOIN using the query builder, there will be no less queries.

I would not worry about the amount of queries since these are very simple and fast, unless you are expecting a great amount of requests.

---

Edit: Actually, it is possible to reduce the amount of queries used for the updates, but since you have to retrieve the Wallet anyway (to retrieve its ID to write to the WalletLog) it does not help much. This only executes two UPDATE statements:

```
User::where('id', $h)->increment('level_count', 1);
Wallet::where('user_id', $h)->increment('wallet_balance', 200);
```